# why does jupyter notebook needs the ubuntu terminal to stay open

Tags: jupyter-notebook, terminal

It may sound silly, pardon me since I'm not an expert in this, and couldn't find the reason for it in my capacity.
I was wondering why the Jupyter Notebook crashes when the terminal that launched it is killed/shut off.
Other software that is launched through the terminal doesn't necessarily follow the same fate.

Comment: There is a local server that is running from that terminal and Jupyter uses that server. When the terminal closes, the local server is gone and Jupyter cannot work. Have you tried [JupyterLab Desktop](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-2022-recap-28bdf00205c6)?

Comment: Mr. @Wayne I've not tried JupyterLab desktop. Though your comment answers it partially, The question is still there, why does the Jupyter needs the server to connect with the python of OS, while many other software such as spyder or pycharm doesn't need a server(I guess).

Comment: Sorry, I think it goes back to how IPython involved in to IPython Notebook which then became Jupyter. I think to make the software work in the browser, it was an implementation choice. I don't know more of the technical aspects of why it is necessary. I think though your post is more about a discussion then a direct issue with a code solution and so it may make more sense by making a more focused post about that exact question in your last comment at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/). And if you do, you should link in each & every place you post a related question.